# Managing rules for e-commerce

Tags: database, database-design

I have a typical e-commerce problem.

my database schema looks like this

```
|product|
---------
|id|
|description|


|product_entry|
|id|
|product_id|
|size_id|
|color_id|


|style|
------
|id|
|style|

|color|
-------
|id|
|name|
```

styles: animal_printed, common, focused
colors: blue, green, yellow

So, my doubt exists when creating a new product.

There are a kind of rules I should follow
animal_printed can only be blue
common can only be blue and yellow
focused can be blue, green or yellow.

Where should I store a that rules in order to fetch them when creating a new product?
Should I just replicate one of the other products?

What about when I have to create a new rule? Should I replicate that rule por all the product?

Comment: One way in your particular example would be to have all the color pairs as options.  animal printed & blue, common & blue, yellow & blue, yellow & green, and yellow & yellow.

Comment: but, where should i store them? in a particular table called options, right?

Comment: Yes.  Create an [entity/attribute/value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) Option table where you can store style, color, size, or any other characteristic of a product.